# JavaScript result not showing in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, phonegap

I'm learning to build an app with PhoneGap and I've made a calculator but result will not show after clicking calculate. Please see the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title>Dog Years Calculator</title>
        <script>
            windows.onload=function{
                    document.getElementById('btnCalc').addEventListener('click', calcAge);
                }       
                function calcAge(e)
                {
                    var age = document.getElementById('dogAge').value;
                    age = age * 7;
                    var result = "In Dog years, your dogs age is: " + age;
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <h1>Dog Years Calculator</h1>
        <label for="dogAge">Dogs age in Human years:</label>
        <input id="dogAge" type="number" />
        <button id="btnCalc">Calculate</button>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's 'window', not 'windows' and you forgot the parentheses after the function keyword on the same line. Use the dev tools of your browser to find such errors.

Comment: Please edit your question to include errors (you will find them in your browser's console view), as well as steps that you took to troubleshoot the problem. Asking for a ready solution to your problem is likely going to attract negative votes.

Answer (score 0):

Use Like This :

```js
 btnCalc.onclick = function(){
                    var age = document.getElementById('dogAge').value;
                    age = age * 7;
                    var result = "In Dog years, your dogs age is: " + age;
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
                };
```

```html
        <h1>Dog Years Calculator</h1>
        <label for="dogAge">Dogs age in Human years:</label>
        <input id="dogAge" type="number" />
        <button id="btnCalc">Calculate</button>
        <div id="result"></div>
```